# Remove html tags from I18n "translation missing" messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, i18n-gem

Consider the following code in a view:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete!', item ,  :confirm => t('action.item.confirm_deletion'), :method => :delete %>
```

It will normally come out as:

```
<a href="/items/123" data-confirm="Confirm deletion?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete!</a>
```

But if the translation for **action.item.confirm_deletion** is missing for some reason (incomplete yml-file, typos, etc.) it comes out as:

```
<a href="/items/123" data-confirm="<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: sv.action.item.confirm_deletion">Confirm Deletion</span>" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete!</a>
```

which is invalid html, and user will see broken html tags on the homepage.
It may also be a security risk in some cases.

I know that I could use apply some escaping on every call to the I18n.t function, but that feels unnecessarily repetitive for the task.

So my question is:
Is there a way to make the "translation missing"-messages not contain html code.

Comment: Not too good and answer since it is per-t() call: `t('action.item.confirm_deletion', :default => 'Are you sure you want to delete this thing?')`

Comment: Thanks anyway! It's always good to know that possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for you.

You can alias the translation method to your own and call with the custom `:default` value (I would prefer this way):

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module TranslationHelper
      alias_method :translate_without_default :translate

      def translate(key, options = {})
        options.merge!(:default => "translation missing: #{key}") unless options.key?(:default)
        translate_without_default(key, options)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Or you can overwrite the default value:

```
module I18n
  class MissingTranslation
    def html_message
      "translation missing: #{keys.join('.')}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! According to your second tip, i wrote a plain text version,  replacing the empty quotes with
%(Translation missing: #{keys.join('.')})

Comment: Overwriting the default value is not working on rails 4.2!

Answer (score 1):

In rails 4.2 you have to redefine the `translate` helper in the view:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.5/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb#L78

In rails 5 you can set in your application.rb:

```
config.action_view.debug_missing_translation = false
```